# Problem with line spacing in Lyx 1.6.9

Tags: lyx, line-spacing

Maybe it's a silly thing, but in order to change line spacing to Double I have to "navigate" to Document>>Settings>>Text layout. If I click on the icon `Paragraph Settings` from the Lyx toolbar and change it to `Double`, it doesn't work, as it keeps the current setting (Single). I don't think it's a bug, but it seems weird. Why doesn't the shortcut work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LyX 2.0 at least, the setting in Document --> Settings is a global switch, so it applies for the whole document, while the button on the toolbar is local, applying only for the current paragraph. Hence, they serve different purposes, if you wish to set the same style for the entire document, use the former.

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense. If I Edit>>Select All and then use the button,it applies to the whole document.